# With a browser, how do I know which decimal separator the operating system uses?

Tags: html, internationalization, locale

I'm developing a Web application.

I need to display some decimal data correctly so that it can be copied and pasted into a certain GUI application that is not under my control.

The GUI application is locale-sensitive and it accepts only the correct decimal separator that is set in the system.

I can guess the decimal separator from `Accept-Language` and the guess will be correct in 95% cases, but sometimes it fails.

Is there any way to do it on server side (preferably, so that I can collect statistics), or on client side?

**Update:**

The whole point of the task is doing it automatically.

In fact, this Web application is a kind of online interface to a legacy GUI that helps to fill the forms correctly.

The kind of users that use it mostly have no idea on what a decimal separator is.

The `Accept-Language` solution is implemented and works, but I'd like to improve it.

**Update2:**

I need to retrive a very specific setting: decimal separator set in Control Panel / Regional and Language Options / Regional Options / Customize.

I deal with four kinds of operating systems:

1. Russian Windows with a comma as a DS (80%).
2. English Windows with a point as a DS (15%).
3. Russian Windows with a point as a DS to make poorly written English applications work (4%).
4. English Windows with a comma as a DS to make poorly written Russian applications work (1%).

All clients are in Russia and the legacy application deals with Russian goverment-issued forms, so asking for a country will yield 100% of Russian Federation, and GeoIP will yield 80% of Russian Federation and 20% of other (incorrect) answers.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Here is a simple JavaScript function that will return this information. Tested in Firefox, IE6, and IE7.  I had to close and restart my browser in between every change to the setting under Control Panel / Regional and Language Options / Regional Options / Customize.  However, it picked up not only the comma and period, but also oddball custom things, like the letter "a".

```
function whatDecimalSeparator() {
    var n = 1.1;
    n = n.toLocaleString().substring(1, 2);
    return n;
}
```

```js
function whatDecimalSeparator() {
    var n = 1.1;
    n = n.toLocaleString().substring(1, 2);
    return n;
}

console.log('You use "' + whatDecimalSeparator() + '" as Decimal seprator');
```

Does this help?

Comment: This worked for me in Firefox and IE8, but not Google Chrome. I don't have Opera.

Comment: @Matthew - worked for me in Chrome. @Quassnoi - I don't get what that last comment means. If he's saying that the function doesn't work, then what does it matter what the person knows?

Comment: Watch out! In Chrome toLocaleString only works properly if called directly on a Number. On my system:
[1.1,1.2].toLocaleString() -> "1.1,1.2" |
(1.1).toLocaleString() -> "1,1"

Comment: Function fails on locale's that use more than one character for their `DecimalSeparator` (e.g. **`,,`**). Windows [`LOCALE_SDECIMAL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows a decimal separator to contain up to three characters. (Which is why it fails on my PC). Better to use the `Accept-Language` of the browser in that case. Which still doesn't account for the ability to specify their own `DecimalSeparator` e.g. **`\o/`**

Comment: @IanBoyd is right about locales with a string of more than one character as decimal separator, but `n = /^1(.+)1$/.exec(n.toLocaleString())[1]` would do it, and is easier than using the `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: @IanBoyd for the sake of curiosity... which locale are you using?

Comment: @ygormutti I'm testing with [the `qps-PLOC` locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042920/how-to-use-enable-pseudo-locale-in-windows-for-testing). You can [add the accept-language to Chrome and IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769061/how-to-add-custom-accept-languages-to-chrome-for-pseudolocalization-testing)

Comment: Today I noticed that the approach stopped to work with Firefox. I'm on FF 55.0.3. 1.1 becomes "1.1" ignoring Windows regional settings unlike IE/Edge.

Answer (score 27):

Retrieving separators for the current or a given locale is possible using `Intl.NumberFormat#formatToParts`.

```
function getDecimalSeparator(locale) {
    const numberWithDecimalSeparator = 1.1;
    return Intl.NumberFormat(locale)
        .formatToParts(numberWithDecimalSeparator)
        .find(part => part.type === 'decimal')
        .value;
}
```

It only works for [browsers supporting the Intl API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization). Otherwise it requires an [Intl polyfill](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/)

**Examples:**

```
> getDecimalSeparator()
"."
> getDecimalSeparator('fr-FR')
","
```

**Bonus:**

We could extend it to retrieve either the **decimal** or **group** separator of a given locale:

```
function getSeparator(locale, separatorType) {
        const numberWithGroupAndDecimalSeparator = 1000.1;
        return Intl.NumberFormat(locale)
            .formatToParts(numberWithGroupAndDecimalSeparator)
            .find(part => part.type === separatorType)
            .value;
    }
```

Examples:

```
> getSeparator('en-US', 'decimal')
"."
> getSeparator('en-US', 'group')
","
> getSeparator('fr-FR', 'decimal')
","
> getSeparator('fr-FR', 'group')
" "
```

Comment: Currently this is the most proper way to get such info. BTW `Intl` is supported even in IE 11: https://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization

Comment: This won't be working in IE 11 as formatToParts is not supported.

Answer (score 13):

Ask the user, do not guess. Have a setting for it in your Web application.

Edited to add:

I think it is OK to guess the *default* setting that works, say, 95% of the time. What I meant was that the user should still be able to override whatever guesses the software made. I've been frustrated too many times already when a software tries to be too smart and does not allow to be corrected.

Comment: Funny, it was my first idea, but I went overboard looking how to do it automatically...

Comment: Bad idea, except maybe as a backup. Most users are embarassinlgy culture-insensitive and won't even understand what a "decimal separator" is without explanation (and then will be pissed off at being forced to set something that "everyone knows").

Comment: @Iaalto: this would make a question almost as great as "Minimize database size (recommended) or Maximize search capabilities?"

Comment: Well, that shouldn't be too hard. Just let the user choose the country and then select the desicmal separator and other options accordingly.

Comment: :) please tweet this, I want to repost this. `I've been frustrated too many times already when a software tries to be too smart and does not allow to be corrected.`

Answer (score 12):

Why not

```js
console.log(0.1.toLocaleString().replace(/\d/g, ''));
```

Comment: maybe some strange locale may skip the leading zero? I'd rather have a one there, just to be sure.

Comment: I do like the lateral thinking to look at what the browser is doing rather than what it has been told to so. But I gave my upvote to the answer from @ashleedawg, currently below, because that has the implementation I find easiest.

Answer (score 8):

```
function getDecimalSeparator() {
    //fallback  
       var decSep = ".";

        try {
            // this works in FF, Chrome, IE, Safari and Opera
            var sep = parseFloat(3/2).toLocaleString().substring(1,2);
            if (sep === '.' || sep === ',') {
                decSep = sep;
            }
        } catch(e){}

        return decSep;
    }
```

Comment: the fallback to "." in case of some obscure browsers ... other ways it is pretty much the same thing ...

Answer (score 5):

> I can guess the decimal separator from
>   Accept-Language and the guess will be
>   correct in 95% cases, but sometimes it
>   fails.

This is IMO the best course of action. In order to handle the failures, add a link to set it manually next to the display area.

Comment: How would this be done?  I understand you can use a browser library like this https://github.com/dansingerman/jQuery-Browser-Language

Comment: @William: The Acccept-Language that OP talks about is a HTTP header sent by the browser which tells the server what langugage the user prefers, usually the language of the browser installation or the OS.

Comment: the user already has it configured in his system settings, which flow through to his browser. why would you let him configure it again?

Comment: @Davy: The Accept-Language header is set to the system language *by default*, but can be changed individually, and there may be all kinds of weird setups where it's not what you need. As OP wrote explicitly in the part I quoted.

Answer (score 5):

Using other people answers I compiled the following decimal and thousand separators utility functions:

```
var decimalSeparator = function() {
    return (1.1).toLocaleString().substring(1, 2);
};
var thousandSeparator = function() {
    return (1000).toLocaleString().substring(1, 2);
};
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Yes, I used this method as a polyfill for browsers which don't support `formatToParts` (Safari and IE).

Comment: Some locales do not use thousand separators below 10000. For example `(1000).toLocaleString("es-PE") # "1000"`

Comment: @Madacol  ` (1000).toLocaleString("es-PE")` is currently giving me `1,000` in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Is there some other setting that gets involved, or has it been corrected/made wrong sometime in the last 2.5 years?

Comment: @zsalya it's probably been fixed!, because Peru didn't use that format. But you can still see how it works in the spanish version of some non-spanish countries, for example spanish England `(1000).toLocaleString("es-EN") # "1000"`. My point is that it has been deliberately implemented, so it probably holds true for some locales

Answer (score 3):

Similar to other answers, but **compressed as a constant**:

```javascript
const decimal=.1.toLocaleString().substr(1,1);      //returns "." in Canada
```

Also, to get the **thousands separator**:

```
const thousands=1234..toLocaleString().substr(1,1);   //returns "," in Canada
```

Just place the code at the top of your JS and then call as required to return the symbol.

---

**For example** (where I live), to remove commas from `"1,234,567"`:

```
console.log( "1,234,567".replaceAll(thousands,"") ); //prints "1234567" to console.
```

Comment: Per comment from @Juangui Jordán on a different answer, slightly safer to have a number greater than 1 for the decimal i.e. 9.9 at the beginning rather than .1

Comment: And while the "thousands" formula will give the right character, what it gives you is for India is the 10^(3+2n) separator rather than the 10^(3n) separator.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you knew what locale this "GUI Application" is running under, you still have to figure out how *it* is getting the current locale, and how *it* is determining the decimal separator.

I don't know how it is done on a Mac, but Windows applications are supposed to interrogte the user's preferences set via the Control Panel. It's quite possible this mystery applicaiton is ignoring those settings, and using their own internal setup instead.

Or perhaps they're taking the current locale, and inferring the rest, rather than being told.

Even then, in English, **numbers** are given in groups of three digits, with a comma separating the groups, i.e.:

```
5,197,359,078
```

Unless the number was an integer that contains a **phone number**:

```
519-735-9078
```

Unless of course the number was an integer that contains an **account number**:

```
5197359078
```

In which case, you're back to hard-coded overridden logic.

Edit: Removed currency example, since currency has its own formatting rules.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to rely on JavaScript to give you the locale settings.
But apparently JS doesn't have direct access to this information.
I see [Dojo Toolkit](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/HEAD/dojo.currency.format) relies on an external database to find the locale information, although it might not take in account setting changes, for example.
Another workaround I see is to have a small silent Java applet that query this information from the system, and JavaScript to get it out of Java.
I can give more information if you don't know how to do it (if you want to go this convoluted route, of course).

[EDIT]
So I updated my knowledge of localization support in Java...
Unlike what I thought originally, you won't have directly the decimal separator or thousand separator characters directly, like you would do with line separator or path separator: instead Java offers APIs to format the numbers or dates you provide.
Somehow, it makes sense: in Europe you often put the currency symbol after the number, some countries (India?) have a more complex rule to separate digits, etc.

Another thing: Java correctly finds the current locale from the system, but doesn't take information from there (perhaps for above reasons). Instead it uses its own set of rules. So if you have a Spanish locale where you replaced decimal separator with an exclamation sign, Java won't use it (but perhaps neither your application, anyway...).

So I am writing an applet exposing a service (functions) to JavaScript, allowing to format numbers to the current locale. You can use it as such, using JavaScript to format numbers on the browser. Or you can just feed it with some sample number and extract the symbols from there, using them locally or feeding them back to the server.

I finish and test my applet and post it there soon.

Comment: @PhiLho: would be nice to know. This webapp is a kind of a help system, so any ugly hack will do, it doesn't need to be elegant as long as it runs on IE, Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have something to show, more a proof of concept than a finished product, but because of lack of precise specifications, I leave it this way (or I will over-engineer it). I post in a separate message because it will be a bit long.
I took the opportunity to try a bit more jQuery...

The Java code:
**GetLocaleInfo.java**

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.*;

public class GetLocaleInfo extends Applet
{
  Locale loc;
  NumberFormat nf;
  NumberFormat cnf;
  NumberFormat pnf;

  // For running as plain application
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    final Applet applet = new GetLocaleInfo();
    applet.init();
    applet.start();
  }

  public void init() // Applet is loaded
  {
    // Use current locale
    loc = Locale.getDefault();
    nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    cnf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    pnf = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
  }

  public void start() // Applet should start
  {
    // Following output goes to Java console
    System.out.println(GetLocaleInformation());
    System.out.println(nf.format(0.1));
    System.out.println(cnf.format(1.0));
    System.out.println(pnf.format(0.01));
  }

  public String GetLocaleInformation()
  {
    return String.format("Locale for %s: country=%s (%s / %s), lang=%s (%s / %s), variant=%s (%s)",
        loc.getDisplayName(),
        loc.getDisplayCountry(),
        loc.getCountry(),
        loc.getISO3Country(),

        loc.getDisplayLanguage(),
        loc.getLanguage(),
        loc.getISO3Language(),

        loc.getDisplayVariant(),
        loc.getVariant()
    );
  }

  public String FormatNumber(String number)
  {
    double value = 0;
    try
    {
      value = Double.parseDouble(number);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
      return "!";
    }
    return nf.format(value);
  }

  public String FormatCurrency(String number)
  {
    double value = 0;
    try
    {
      value = Double.parseDouble(number);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
      return "!";
    }
    return cnf.format(value);
  }

  public String FormatPercent(String number)
  {
    double value = 0;
    try
    {
      value = Double.parseDouble(number);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
      return "!";
    }
    return pnf.format(value);
  }
}
```

An example of HTML page using the above applet:
**GetLocaleInfo.html**

```
<!-- Header skipped for brevity -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var applet;
$(document).ready(function()
{
  applet = document.getElementById('LocaleInfo');
  $('#Results').text(applet.GetLocaleInformation());
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function DoFormatting()
{
  $('table.toFormat').each(function()
  {
    var table = $(this);
    $('td', table).each(function(cellId)
    {
      var val = $(this);
      if (val.is('.number'))
      {
        val.text(applet.FormatNumber(val.text()));
      }
      else if (val.is('.currency'))
      {
        val.text(applet.FormatCurrency(val.text()));
      }
      else if (val.is('.percent'))
      {
        val.text(applet.FormatPercent(val.text()));
      }
    });
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Container">
    <p>Page to demonstrate how JavaScript can get locale information from Java</p>
    <div id="AppletContainer">
      <object classid="java:GetLocaleInfo.class"
          type="application/x-java-applet" codetype="application/java"
          name="LocaleInfo" id="LocaleInfo" width="0" height="0">
        <param name="code" value="GetLocaleInfo"/>
        <param name="mayscript" value="true"/>
        <param name="scriptable" value="true"/>
        <p><!-- Displayed if object isn't supported -->
          <strong>This browser does not have Java enabled.</strong>
          <br>
          <a href="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/downloads/index.html" title="Download Java plug-in">
          Get the latest Java plug-in here
          </a> (or enable Java support).
        </p>
      </object>
    </div><!-- AppletContainer -->
    <p>
    Click on the button to format the table content to the locale rules of the user.
    </p>
    <input type="button" name="DoFormatting" id="DoFormatting" value="Format the table" onclick="javascript:DoFormatting()"/>
    <div id="Results">
    </div><!-- Results -->
<table class="toFormat">
<caption>Synthetic View</caption>
<thead><tr>
<th>Name</th><th>Value</th><th>Cost</th><th>Discount</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Foo</td><td class="number">3.1415926</td><td class="currency">21.36</td><td class="percent">0.196</td></tr>
<tr><td>Bar</td><td class="number">159263.14</td><td class="currency">33</td><td class="percent">0.33</td></tr>
<tr><td>Baz</td><td class="number">15926</td><td class="currency">12.99</td><td class="percent">0.05</td></tr>
<tr><td>Doh</td><td class="number">0.01415926</td><td class="currency">5.1</td><td class="percent">0.1</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  </div><!-- Container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Tested on Firefox 3.0, IE 6, Safari 3.1 and Opera 9.50, on Windows XP Pro SP3.
It works without problem with the first two, on Safari I have a strange error after init() call:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.checkLiveConnectCaller(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.CallMethod(Unknown Source)
```

but it still works.

I can't get it work with Opera: the applet loads correctly, as I can see the trace of init() call in the Java console, I have no errors when JavaScript calls the Java functions (except if I add and call a method getting a JSObject parameter, curiously), but the Java functions are not called (I added trace of the calls).
I believe Liveconnect works in Opera, but I don't see yet how. I will research a bit more.
[Update] I removed references to non-existing jar file (which doesn't stop other browsers) and I got a trace of the calls, but it doesn't update the page.
Mmm, if I do `alert(applet.GetLocaleInformation());` I got the information, so it might be a jQuery issue.

Comment: @PhiLho: it works, but still doesn't read the separator correctly from Windows. When it sees the following: `Locale for русский (Россия): country=Россия (RU / RUS), lang=русский (ru / rus), variant= ()` it uses a comma despite the fact that I've overridden it with a period in the Windows settings.

Comment: Please, read my update of my first message about limitations of this system. I don't know if we can do better from a Web browser, except by using some native code perhaps.

Answer (score -1):

> "Is there any way to do it on server
>   side (preferably, so that I can
>   collect statistics), or on client
>   side?"

No you can't. That GUI is looking at some user or machine specific settings. 
First, you probably do not know at what settings this UI is looking. 
Second, with a webapplication you will probably not be able to check these settings (clientside --> Javacsript).

Comment: @RWC: I know where the GUI app is looking to: the Windows regional settings.

Answer (score -2):

> Is there any way to do it on server side (preferably, so that I can collect statistics), or on client side?

from Server side. That could get decimal separator from system by (.NET)

```
string x = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDsecimalSeparator;
```

The rest of work is check delimiter for exporting which is different from **x**
comma (",") or semicolon (";") in case **csv** export

Answer (score -4):

Another possible solution: You could use something like [GeoIP](http://www.php.net/manual/book.geoip.php) (example in PHP) to determine the user's location and decide based on these information.

Comment: It would be necessary to allow the user to override this, though. A friend of mine works in the South of England; the company he works for routes all Internet access through a proxy server in Spain, so GeoIP always shows him as being many hundreds of miles from his actual location.