# What is the decimal separator symbol in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, syntax, decimal-point

A thought struck me as I was writing a piece of JavaScript code that processed some floating point values. What is the decimal point symbol in JavaScript? Is it always `.`? Or is it culture-specific? And what about `.toFixed()` and `.parseFloat()`?  If I'm processing a user input, it's likely to include the local culture-specific decimal separator symbol.

Ultimately I'd like to write code that supports both decimal points in user input - culture-specific and `.`, but I can't write such a code if I don't know what JavaScript expects.

**Added:** OK, Rubens Farias [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085275/what-is-the-decimal-separator-symbol-in-javascript/2085307#2085307) to look at [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074660/with-a-browser-how-do-i-know-which-decimal-separator-does-the-client-use) which has a neat accepted answer:

```
function whatDecimalSeparator() {
    var n = 1.1;
    n = n.toLocaleString().substring(1, 2);
   return n;
}
```

That's nice, it lets me get the locale decimal point. A step towards the solution, no doubt.

Now, the remaining part would be to determine what the behavior of `.parseFloat()` is. Several answers point out that for floating point literals only `.` is valid. Does `.parseFloat()` act the same way? Or might it require the local decimal separator in some browser? Are there any different methods for parsing floating point numbers as well? Should I roll out my own just-to-be-sure?

Comment: @Vilx- for what you're doing, I would consider using the unary (+) operator instead of `parseFloat()`.  It will be much easier when validating input.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the specification, a DecimalLiteral is defined as:

```
DecimalLiteral ::
    DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigitsopt ExponentPartopt 
    . DecimalDigits ExponentPartopt 
    DecimalIntegerLiteral ExponentPartopt
```

and for satisfying the parseFloat argument:

1. Let inputString be ToString(string).
2. Let trimmedString be a substring of inputString consisting of the leftmost character that is not a StrWhiteSpaceChar and all characters to the right of that character.(In other words, remove leading white space.)
3. If neither trimmedString nor any prefix of trimmedString satisfies the syntax of a StrDecimalLiteral (see 9.3.1), return NaN.
4. Let numberString be the longest prefix of trimmedString, which might be trimmedString itself, that satisfies the syntax of a StrDecimalLiteral.
5. Return the Number value for the MV

So numberString becomes the longest prefix of trimmedString that satisfies the syntax of a StrDecimalLiteral, meaning the first parseable literal string number it finds in the input.  Only the `.` can be used to specify a floating-point number.  If you're accepting inputs from different locales, use a string replace:

```
function parseLocalNum(num) {
    return +(num.replace(",", "."));
}
```

The function uses the unary operator instead of parseFloat because it seems to me that you want to be strict about the input.  `parseFloat("1ABC")` would be `1`, whereas using the unary operator `+"1ABC"` returns `NaN`.  This makes it MUCH easier to validate the input.  Using parseFloat is just guessing that the input is in the correct format.

Comment: That's for literals. Is `.parseFloat()` required to do the same?

Comment: Yes. `parseFloat("1,01")` in any locale will return `1`, not `1.01`

Comment: Mozilla Developer Centre says: "parseFloat parses its argument, a string, and returns a floating point number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -), numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding characters. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseFloat

Comment: @Vilx- parseFloat looks for the first matching DecimalLiteral in the string that is passed as the argument.  Anything else will return NaN.

Comment: Except that it conveniently doesn't define "decimal point". XD

Comment: Because that's already defined in the ECMAScript 262 specs for DecimalLiteral :)

Comment: @Vilx- It defines a DecimalLiteral, and the DecimalLiteral defines the decimal point :)

Comment: OK, I'll take your word for it! :)

Comment: @Vilx- LOL it's not my word, it's ECMA International's word!

Comment: I'll take your word because I'm too lazy to look up the spec myself. XD Thanks! :)

Comment: In case anyone wants to check the ECMA specs: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#prod-DecimalLiteral

Comment: That last function doesn't cover all possible decimal separators - I've had issues before caused by people sending numbers with the Persian Decimal Separator ("momayyez") special unicode character, or a forward slash sometimes used in its place

Answer (score 15):

use:

```
theNumber.toLocaleString();
```

to get a properly formatted string with the right decimal and thousands separators

Comment: OK. And how do I parse a string with these separators?

Comment: you'd need to strip out the seps, and make sure it conforms to something like: [\+\-]?([0-9]+|[0-9]*(\.([eE][\+\-]?[0-9]+))?)

Comment: Fair enough, I can strip whatever is needed, and can replace the locale-specific separator with `.`. But is `.` the only thing that `.parseFloat()` expects?

Comment: See replies to Andy E's original answer (short answer: yes)

Comment: I tried this in Google Chrome and do not see the "thousands separators"

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, javascript itself only knows about the `.` separator for decimals. At least one person whose judgement I trust on JS things concurs:

http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-maths.htm#DTS

Comment: To add to this, see the old ECMAScript 262 specification on grammar wrt parsing numeric literals: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.8.3

Comment: Ah yes, always good to have official documentation for this sort of thing, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that's for literals. What about parsing string input?

Comment: Take a fixed number such as 1234.56 and run it through the `.toLocaleString()` method mentioned by jspcal. Examine the result to work out what your decimal and thousand separators are. Run all numbers displayed to the user through a function which applies those separators (see the link I gave for examples of that).