# Simple data validation and math operation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I need to create a simple calculator that computes 1% of the value submitted by the user. I also need to round it (floor) to the tenth part after colon.

Examples:

```
input    1%        output
12.34    0.1234    0.10
2345.34  23.4534   23.40
```

More info:
- users will submit monetary values. They can use dots or comma to separate the parts of the value. Both inputs `123.45` and `123,45` are valid.
- I need to calculate 1% of it, round it and display in "user friendly" form, for example `XX.YY`

I created following function so far. But it rounds the value in odd way. For example, for input "`123.45`" the output is `1.2000000000000002` (should be `1.20`).

```
function calc(val)
{
var x = 0.1*Math.floor(0.1*val);
alert("your 1% is:\n"+x);
}
```

Javascript treats only values with dots as numbers. How can I easily convert values with commas to numbers?

And how to display the outcome with desired precision?

Comment: Are users allowed to enter numbers with thousands/millions/etc separators? E.g. `1,234,567.89` and `1.234.567,89`?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074660/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085275/) for info about working with different decimal separators.

Comment: No, it is rather not expected. I really do not have to deal with thousand/etc separators. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val = parseFloat(val.toString().replace(",", ".")); // just replace comma with dot
var x = (0.1*Math.floor(0.1*val)).toFixed(2); // toFixed leaves required amount of digits after dicimal dot.
alert("your 1% is:\n"+x);
```