# Result format right Jquery Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-calculation

I have a code fast and quiet, but results in some calculations are formatted very large, including, the value obtained does not enter the calculation. How to do this see the right result?

I would like the result of the calculation (3 * 2215.40) was 3 646.20 and non 3.6450000000000005.

How?

Code - http://jsfiddle.net/bruno_aw/M7JZu/

```
$(".calc_cub").on("keyup", ".qtd", function(){
    var valorCub = $("#CUB").text();        
    var number = parseFloat(valorCub);  
    var qtd = +$(this).val();
    $(".total").text(number * qtd).val().toFixed(2);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get the number out of the text.  You are also calling .val() after you set the text on .total - which all you need to really do is `$(".total").text((number * qtd).toFixed(2))`;

```
$(".calc_cub").on("keyup", ".qtd", function () {
    var valorCub = $("#CUB").text().split(' '); // returns ["Valor", "CUB", "R$", "1,215.40"]
    var number = parseFloat(valorCub[valorCub.length - 1].replace(',','')); // get last one in array and remove comma
    var qtd = +$(this).val();
    $(".total").text((number * qtd).toFixed(2));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GMjjc/

Comment: OW Man!!
I tried several times to use the replace and format, plus the slit did not know.
Congratulations and thank you.
perfect @wirey
Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome :)  I didn't know if you had a typo in your html or not but I changed it to from `1.215,40` to `1,215.40`

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
$(".total").text((number * qtd).toFixed(2));
```

Note that in your fiddle the `CUB` div has text and digits. `parseFloat()` works when the number is at the front of the string. So you will need to arrange things so the number is isolated. You can do it like this:

```
<div>Some text is here <span id="CUB">1234.50</span></div>
```

Comment: Exactly, but could not catch the value excluding the "," number.  :(

Comment: Ok!

Got the whole problem is the "."

This value is the client that uses a table in google docs DataTables. 'll To have to ask take the ",".

Thank you Lee Meador, have my gratitude.

Comment: You might read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085275/what-is-the-decimal-separator-symbol-in-javascript as it discusses the use of international number formatting differences and dealing with them for parseFloat().

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up the string of the text block and the separators for the float. Try this;

http://jsfiddle.net/M7JZu/8/

**JavaScript**

```
$(".calc_cub").on("keyup", ".qtd", function () {
    var valorCub = $("#CUB").text();
    valorCub = parseFloat(valorCub.split('$ ')[1].replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
    var qtd = $(this).val();
    $(".total").text(valorCub * qtd);
});
```

For output-sakes, you can convert the `.` back to a `,` (comma) again on output.