# Change decimal separator

Tags: javascript

I have to round a number to 2 decimal places in javascript. But I also have to change the decimal separator from "." to ",".

I found out a few post on how to round the number to 2 decimal places

[How to round1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)
[How to round2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

I found a few in hot to change the decimal separator

[Change Decimal Separator1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085275/what-is-the-decimal-separator-symbol-in-javascript)
[Change Decimal Separator2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript/2866613#2866613)

But they all manipulate the string, changing the "," for ".", or something like that. There is no direct way to set the decimal separator? Like a global configuration?

Comment: This is a localization issue.

Comment: Can you just find and replace for the "." and change to a ","?

Comment: william I can do that... but it's seems wrong xD, why can't I have the result directly in the correct way?

Comment: It's not my first problem with location, I struggled a little bit with date, but my solution only solved the date problem

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to do this:

```
function decimalSeparator($yourInt){
 return parseInt( $yourInt ).toLocaleString()
}
```

EDIT Check this solution:

```
        function formatDK(num, decimals) {
            return formatLocale(num, decimals, '.', ',');
        } //for dk
        function formatUK(num, decimals) {
            return formatLocale(num, decimals, ',', '.');
        }  //for Uk 
        function formatLocale(num, decimals, kilosep, decimalsep) {
            var i, bNeg = num < 0, x = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, decimals)), y = Math.abs(x).toString().split(''), z = y.length - decimals;

            if (z <= 0) {
                for (i = 0; i <= -z; i += 1) {
                    y.unshift('0');
                }
                z = 1;
            }
            if (decimals > 0) {
                y.splice(z, 0, decimalsep);
            }
            while (z > 3) {
                z -= 3;
                y.splice(z, 0, kilosep);
            }
            if (bNeg) {
                y.splice(0, 0, '-');
            }
            return y.join('');
        }
```

There is no global config for this, you will have to use this method, i recommend you to define this and use it in all places, that its what i do.

Comment: Well, I didn't get the idea =/. With that function I'll only get the "integer" value of the number. Or did I understand it wrong?

Comment: change parseInt for 
parseFloat($yourInt).toLocaleString().toFixed(2) //this is to get 2 decimals

Comment: If I do so, I will have the number with 2 decimals, but I'll still have the "." instenad of "," problem

Comment: Rafael the . is becouse of the locale of your computer, people with another locale on his browser must see this correctly, but try my edit upside