# Math.round doesn't work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code is working fine until I add the line inside the function

```
parseLocalFloatCnt: num = Math.round(num*1.2);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = parseLocalFloatCnt(document.getElementById("myInput").value);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
}
function parseLocalFloatCnt(num) {
    num = Math.round(num*1.2);
    return +(num.replace(getLocalDecimalSeparator(), '.'));
}

function getLocalDecimalSeparator() {
    var n = 1.1;
    return n.toLocaleString().substring(1,2);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain what you try to do?

Comment: in your function: `Math.round` return _Number_, you try do `toString` replace separator, and again try get same _Number_, but why??? if you do `return Math.round(num*1.2)` result would be same

Comment: also see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085275/what-is-the-decimal-separator-symbol-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

```
Uncaught TypeError: num.replace is not a function(…)
```

You can't call `replace` on a number.

You *could* do this instead:

```
function parseLocalFloatCnt(num) {
    num = Math.round(num*1.2) + ''; // convert `num` to string
    return +(num.replace(getLocalDecimalSeparator(), '.'));
}
```

Comment: in this case also possibly use `toFixed` instead `Math.round`

Comment: @Grundy: That is one of the _many_ possible improvements here ;-) I'm not sure what exactly the OP is trying to do with this code.

Comment: yep, also OP pass string in this function, so it can return a `NaN` also, i think :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget num to.String();

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = parseLocalFloatCnt(document.getElementById("myInput").value);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
    }
    function parseLocalFloatCnt(num) {
        num = Math.round(num*1.2).toString();

        return +(num.replace(getLocalDecimalSeparator(), '.'));
    }

    function getLocalDecimalSeparator() {
        var n = 1.1;
        return n.toLocaleString().substring(1,2);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```