# jQuery can't order numbers with thousands dot separated ordering

Tags: jquery

With the following jQuery code to order table rows, numbers with dot for thousands formatting are not ordering correctly:

These numbers:

> 1.000, 2.500, 4.000, 850

are ordered as:

> 850, 4.000, 2.500, 1.000

I need order these sample numbers without remove the dot.

The jQuery code:

```
$('th').each(function (column) {
    $(this).addClass('sortable').click(function () {
        var findSortKey = function ($cell) {
            return $cell.find('.sort-key').text().toUpperCase()+ ' ' + $cell.text().toUpperCase();

        };
        var sortDirection = $(this).is('.sorted-asc') ? -1 : 1;
        var $rows = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('tbody tr').get();
        var bob = 0;
        // Loop through all records and find
        $.each($rows, function (index, row) {
            row.sortKey = findSortKey($(row).children('td').eq(column));
        });

        // Compare and sort the rows alphabetically or numerically
        $rows.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.sortKey.indexOf('-') == -1 && (!isNaN(a.sortKey) && !isNaN(a.sortKey))) {
                 // Rough Numeracy check

                    if (parseInt(a.sortKey) < parseInt(b.sortKey)) {
                        return -sortDirection;
                    }
                    if (parseInt(a.sortKey) > parseInt(b.sortKey)) {
                        return sortDirection;
                    }

            } else {
                if (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) {
                    return -sortDirection;
                }
                if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey) {
                    return sortDirection;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        });

        // Add the rows in the correct order to the bottom of the table
        $.each($rows, function (index, row) {
            $('tbody').append(row);
            row.sortKey = null;
        });

        // Identify the column sort order
        $('th').removeClass('sorted-asc sorted-desc');
        var $sortHead = $('th').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')');
        sortDirection == 1 ? $sortHead.addClass('sorted-asc') : $sortHead.addClass('sorted-desc');

        // Identify the column to be sorted by
        $('td').removeClass('sorted').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')').addClass('sorted');
    });
});
```

Comment: That's why you ***never*** do sorting on formatted or localized dates, numbers etc.

Comment: Obviously `1.000` is lesser than `850`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar the question you mark as duplicated is about DataTables. This is a custom function, not a plugin. That solution doesn't fit to my requirements.

Comment: @user3472675 Reopened.

Comment: No accepted answer, but have a look at this related/duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645163/how-do-i-convert-string-to-number-according-to-locale-opposite-of-tolocalestri

Comment: [What is the decimal separator symbol in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2085275/215552) includes a solution.

Answer (score 0):

On JavaScript there is not delimiter for thousands numbers. only for decimal and it's `.`

With dot separator you cant define your number variable as `Int` or `float` because this will be considered as decimal number and it remove the zero after decimal.

You can still sort your number with dot.

- Replace dot by empty value ("")
- Sort yours numbers
- And add the dot delimiter as string

Please try:

```js
var numbers = ["4.500", "1.000", "1", "5", "25", "10"];
var num = [];

$.each(numbers,function(i,e){
  dotPos = numbers[i].replace(/\./g,"")
  num.push(parseInt(dotPos))
})
num.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
$.each(num,function(i,e){
  console.log(num[i].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1."))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```