# How to allow comma and dot separator for html5 number input type

Tags: html, input

Is there a way to allow both comma and dot as separator using html5 number input type ?
I found the decimal-separator property but it seems to take only one separator...

Comment: Is there a solution to do so by keeping number input type ? How to work around ?

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible by using input 'number' type. you have to used traditional input 'text' type and apply formatting or regex expression on text leave or keypress event.

Answer (score 0):

No both cannot be used in html5 number input type. In fact it can supports decimal or floating numbers as  well as real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

See an example of my cross-browser [InputKeyFilter](https://github.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter) code, where the user can enter a dot or a comma as decimal separator, depending on the user's system settings.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Input Key Filter Test</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Andrej Hristoliubov anhr@mail.ru">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
 <!-- For compatibility of IE browser with audio element in the beep() function.
 https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible -->
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.css" type="text/css">  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/Common.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
Float field: 
<input type="number" step="any" id="Float"
 onchange="javascript: onChangeFloat(this)"
 onblur="inputKeyFilter.isNaN(parseFloat(this.value), this);"
/>
<script>
 CreateFloatFilter("Float");
 
 function onChangeFloat(input){
  inputKeyFilter.RemoveMyTooltip();
  var elementNewFloat = document.getElementById("NewFloat");
  var float = inputKeyFilter.parseFloat(input.value);
  if(inputKeyFilter.isNaN(float, input)){
   elementNewFloat.innerHTML = "";
   return;
  }
  elementNewFloat.innerHTML = float + " or localized value: " + float.toLocaleString();
 }
</script>
 New float: <span id="NewFloat"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to [Dr.Oblak's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4106812/dr-oblak) answer in [With a browser, how do I know which decimal separator does the client use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074660/with-a-browser-how-do-i-know-which-decimal-separator-does-the-client-use)

Also see my page [example of the input key filter](https://anhr.github.io/InputKeyFilter/).