# Local separator for CSV files generation in Typescript (or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript

I’m looking for the “right” method to determine the list separator in user’s Culture. 
Right now I’m using this code:

```
private static SetSeparator() {
    var list = ['a', 'b'];
    var s = list.toLocaleString();
    var sep = s[1];
    CSVGenerator.Delimiter = sep;
}
```

It works, but seems a little hacky. I’m wondering if there is a documented way to get a local list separator in Typescript (or JavaScript).

I need this information to correctly generate CSV files on the client side. 
Thanks

Comment: toLocaleString() in arrays would be used for parsing date objects or numbers. As far as I know the default ',' separator would never change, unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Actually “,” Is not default, it depends on the current language/country settings of the user. If you are on French settings (for example), your default separator will be “;”.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea. Well your solution does seem 'hacky', but I guess adding a filler character with list.unshift('a') then using the second character index for the delimiter would keep it consistent when the arrays you were getting have first position elements of different lengths.

Comment: The only problem I have is that I’m not sure all countries in the world use ONLY 1 character for separation. That’s why I was asking for some kind of “documented” way to find this(these) character(s)

Comment: Tried with latest chrome in French and I get ',' which is incorrect. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution you have in your answer might be as good as it gets.  Here's a question/answer regarding a similar issue (finding the current locale's decimal separator) - the accepted answer is very similar to the solution in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1308446/1063392

If you're worried about the separator consisting of more than 1 character (although I think that's a reasonable assumption to make), you could make your function select everything between the two characters in your test array instead of blindly taking the character at `[1]`:

```js
function SetSeparator() {
  //var list = ['a', 'b'];
  //var s = list.toLocaleString();
  
  // let's pretend the current separator is ||
  var s = 'a||b';
  
  var reg = /a(.*)b/;
  var sep = reg.exec(s)[1]
  document.writeln('The separator of the current locale is: "' + sep + '"');
}

SetSeparator();
```

Another (possibly better) option might be to remove the first and last characters of the `toLocaleString()` return value - this would avoid the edge case where `a` or `b` are part of the separator:

```js
function SetSeparator() {
  //var list = ['a', 'b'];
  //var s = list.toLocaleString();
  
  // let's pretend the current separator is ab
  var s = 'aabb';

  var sep = s.substr(1, s.length - 2);
  document.writeln('The separator of the current locale is: "' + sep + '"');
}

SetSeparator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this thread is a bit older, but why bother with 'a' and 'b' if you can get the local separator much easier:

var sep = ['',''].toLocaleString();  //   ->  ','